# I'm trying to compile with g++ and i'm getting the below error

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I'm trying to compile with g++ and I'm getting the below error

```
if(nmFunctions && nmFunctions->updateAddressResponseHandler)
```

> error: no match for ‘operator&&’

Comment: it would worth to cite the declarations of your class and nmFunctions (the essential parts)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the object `nmFunctions` cannot be implicitly cast to boolean or doesn't know what to do with the `&&` operator.

From the `->` I guess it could be a `shared_ptr`, in which case you'll need to explicitly cast it to `bool` - `(bool)nmFunctions && ...`.

Note that if the class of `nmFunctions` were to have had either of the below functions, that should have solved your problem. `shared_ptr` uses another version which forces explicit casting.

It should be obvious why the first way is preferred.

```
// allow for "(bool)nmFunctions" or implicit casting
operator bool() { return someBoolean; }

// allow for "nmFunctions && (boolean)"
bool operator&&(bool b) { return b && someBoolean; }
```

Also, `updateAddressResponseHandler` sounds like a function name. If it is, you will need to change it to `updateAddressResponseHandler()`, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: consider this code: `class x {
    public:
    void (*updateAddressResponseHandler)(void);
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    x *nmFunctions = 0;
    
    if(nmFunctions && nmFunctions->updateAddressResponseHandler) {
 nmFunctions = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}`. g++ perfectly compiles it.

Comment: @Serge I'm not quite following the point of your comment. I explained the possible causes of the error (with hopefully enough detail for OP to fix it), not how to build a structure around the given code (which would conflict with the existing code and serve little purpose) to get the given code to work.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that `updateAddressResponseHandler` may be a function pointer. Earlier I have asked the OP to clarify the question, as otherwise any attempts to guess why his code produces compile errors are waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `updateAddressResponseHandler` is a function, and that you want to call it and check its return value. In that case, you need to call it:

```
if(nmFunctions && nmFunctions->updateAddressResponseHandler())
//                                                         ^^
```

If that's not the case, please post the definition of `updateAddressResponseHandler`, and describe what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: That causes a different error (warning), at least on the compiler I'm using - `"the address of updateAddressResponseHandler will always evaluate as 'true'"`.

Comment: @Dukeling: Presumably in your test `updateAddressResponseHandler` is a function pointer. If it's a member function, you'll get a different error again (not a warning) since `nmFunctions->updateAddressResponseHandler` isn't a valid expression in that case. Without more information, we can only guess which is the case.